# Unicode or control sequences?

Tags: unicode, accents, html, punctuation

What kind of troubles may occur if Unicode characters will be entered directly in the following situations (English, no math):

1. Diacritics: for example, `ö` instead of `\"{o}`.
2. Em, en dashes and minuses.
3. Quotes (assuming that it's an English text anyway and rules are applied correctly)

In this domain, what approach (direct Unicode or traditional input) is more flexible in terms of possible export options (html and its archived brother epub)?

Comment: Same question for math: [Unicode in the equations: pros and cons - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87257/unicode-in-the-equations-pros-and-cons)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

there will be no problems except with the packages `soul` or `listings` which cannot handle two byte characters. But there are some tricks to make it also run with `listings` if you have such code in your document.

Comment: Thank you, Herbert. What about tex4ht, will it work smoothly either?

Comment: I never tried it, but it should handle it