# Unicode maths in pdflatex

Tags: math-mode, unicode

In order to use Unicode maths in pdflatex as well as in [LuaTeX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LuaTeX), in preamble of my document I have:

```tex
\usepackage{ifxetex,ifluatex}
\ifnum 0\ifxetex 1\fi\ifluatex 1\fi=0 % if pdftex
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage{textcomp} % provide euro and other symbols
  \usepackage{newunicodechar}
            \newunicodechar{ρ}{\rho}
            \newunicodechar{∈}{\in}
            \newunicodechar{μ}{\mu}
            \newunicodechar{≠}{\neq}
% ... and more of these \newunicodechar
%
\else % if luatex or xetex
  \usepackage{unicode-math}
  \defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
  \defaultfontfeatures[\rmfamily]{Ligatures=TeX,Scale=1}
\fi
```

This allows one to have an arxiv.org-submittable document (arxiv.org does not do LuaTeX).

However, I wonder whether there is actually a package I can use instead of manually writing out all these `\newunicodechar{...}{...}`, as it looks pretty standard to me.

Comment: you are not doing unicode math with these definitions, only a bit of utf8 math input.  And typically it only makes the input slower, I would have no idea how to type ∈, using `\in` is imho much faster. Side remark: in current latex neither textcomp nor inputenc is needed.

Comment: I can think of several reasons. (A) It takes time to include those definitions. (B) Unicode characters are not 1-1 to latex commands, especially `\mathscr` and `\mathcal` mean the same font in Unicode, and *emojic* things like red heart are just begging for troubles. (C) I sometimes want some flexibilities; for instance `\def†#1†{\text{#1}}` and `\def…{,\allowbreak\dotsc,\allowbreak}`. So a good interface is all I need.

Comment: note also ifxetex and ifluatex are legacy packages that both just input `iftex` package you can use `\iftutex` which is true in xetex and luatex rather than teh nested `\ifnum` game.

Comment: I really wouldn't do this (I'd use the command forms when using `unicode-math` package with luatex as well) but if you do want this you can input `unicode-math` package's `unicode-math-table.tex` with a suitable definition of `\UnicodeMathSymbol` which defines the definitions in the "reverse" definition.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer - editors such as VSCode would automatically translate \in to ∈, along with a whole host of other chars (if a pretty standard plugin is used).

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - apart from `newunicodechar`'s, it was what `pandoc` produced after convering a markdown doc with some unicode maths in it to LaTeX.

Comment: ah typical mechanically produced latex,  far more complicated than needed, but Ok.

Comment: Re *"pdflatex"*: Don't you mean [pdfTeX](http://tug.org/applications/pdftex/) (package name "pdftex")? "pdftex" is also used in the second line of comments section of the source.

Comment: I've opened https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/7387 to alert pandoc on the legacy issue.

Comment: Regarding "The source is far clearer if you use the command forms" in the  [answer below](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/601583/250119), see [Unicode in the equations: pros and cons - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/87257/250119)

Comment: This is mostly already answered in [Entering Unicode characters in LaTeX - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34609/250119) ;; however see also the comment below it for utf8x usage.

Comment: @user202729 - thanks, but the world has moved quite a bit on since 2012, when the answer was written. E.g. Lean 
https://leanprover-community.github.io/
with its VSCode interface uses Unicode maths in its interface, and, naturally, people who work with it will tend to type maths this way in texts too...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would not do this. The source is far clearer if you use the command forms (even if using `unicode-math` with LuaTeX).

However, you can input `unicode-math`'s `unicode-math-table.tex`, inverting its normal definition so that it defines the character to expand to the command rather than the other way around.

It is unrelated to the main issue, but most of the autogenerated preamble shown was unnecessarily complicated or redundant. pdfTeX defaults to UTF-8, so `inputenc` isn't needed. TeX ligatures are the default, so it doesn't need to be specified. ifxetex and ifluatex are legacy packages that now do the same thing and both just load iftex.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{iftex,amsmath}

\iftutex
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\else
\usepackage{amssymb}
\def\z"{}
\def\UnicodeMathSymbol#1#2#3#4{%
 \ifnum#1>"A0
   \DeclareUnicodeCharacter{\z#1}{#2}%
  \fi}
\input{unicode-math-table}
\let\muprho\rho
\def\BbbR{\mathbb{R}}
\fi
\begin{document}


$ρ ∈ ℝ$

\end{document}
```

Note that even this small example highlights some issues with using the characters. I took rho from your question, but you used U+03C1 which is the standard ρ which `unicode-math` sets up as `\muprho` (math upright rho), the math italic rho being U+1D70C . I assumed you didn't want the distinction in pdfTeX and added `\let\muprho\rho` and left it to the pdflatex math font setup to decide if that is italic.

So you may find that you still need to add several definitions, but at least inputting `unicode-math-table` defines the bulk of them and any remaining definitions, as here, can be written just using TeX command forms, not needing to refer to code points.

Comment: It would also be possible to load an upright math font in OML encoding as `\mathrm` and define `\muprho` as `\mathrm{\rho}`.  Alternatively, you could load a LGR font for Greek with `mathastext`. This is more-compatible with what h ow `\muprho` works in math mode. (You might or might not need `\muprho` to also work the same way in *text* mode.)  You could also define `\symup` as `\mathrm`. Finally, you could use `\uprho`, which works in both `unicode-math` and many legacy packages.

Comment: @Davislor you are too used to luatex `\mathrm` has no effect on `\rho` :-) Yes I could have forced upright but I doubt that was what was wanted, upright lowercase Greek is essentially never used in math,

Comment: @Davislor oh sorry you were suggesting changing the normal definition of \rho so it was \mathalpha and so \mathrm worked yes I suppose so:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Links to https://github.com/josephwright/siunitx/issues/435 :)

Comment: are the 5 cryptic lines after `\usepackage{amssymb}` doing  "inverting the normal definition" ?

Comment: @DimaPasechnik yes if you look at `unicode-math-table.tex`  you will see that it just consists of thousands of lines each with a single call to `\UnicodeMathSymbol`   unicode-math uses this to _define_ the commands so that the line `\UnicodeMathSymbol{"02208}{\in                       }{\mathrel}{set membership, variant}%`  defines `\in` for that package as the unicode character U+2208, but here you want to define the input U+2208 to the already defined `\in` command. So just define `\UnicodeMathSymbol` to do that and ignore its other arguments.

Comment: Remark: as the original table is meant to *define the command to output the character*, not vice versa, therefore each *command* can appear at most once but each *character* can appear multiple times (which is not an issue in this case because `DeclareUnicodeCharacter` can handle it easily), for example `"00302` corresponds to both `\hat` and `\widehat`.