# Error Message: Argument of � has an extra } but I am not missing any }

Tags: pdftex, sectioning, errors, formatting, compiling

Hello I tried compiling the following text (error location indicated with *********):

```
\section*{Research Issues}

This section identifies research problems and what caused these issues. This section should be as long as it needs to be as it is important to the research program. It is also what characterizes world-class researchers from the rest of the crowd: being able to know exactly what is important and not important. Is is an acquired skill, and usually takes years of experience to acquire it.

*********

\section*{Research Objectives and Plan}

Can be a bulleted list followed by a paragraph describing how you plan at this point to tackle the objectives in the list, i.e. your research plan of attack.
```

After trying to recompile I get this error:

```
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.21 
     
I've run across a `}' that doesn't seem to match anything.
For example, `\def\a#1{...}' and `\a}' would produce
this error. If you simply proceed now, the `\par' that
I've just inserted will cause me to report a runaway
argument that might be the root of the problem. But if
your `}' was spurious, just type `2' and it will go away.
```

I cannot see where I have done anything wrong. Can someone please correct me? Thank you so much! :(

Comment: please provide a small but complete test file

Comment: Oh you have `\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}` ? if so delete.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Sorry, but there is too much that we don't know about your code. Only with this little snippet of code, it is close to impossible to know what is causing the error (given the fact that my crystal ball is out of battery  ...). Please post a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) which shows the problem.

Comment: @JasperHabicht maybe you should borrow mine

Comment: that exact error mssage is here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/654000/argument-of-has-an-extra I would guess this is a duplicate, although you have posted no code related to the error, and you would not get the error using a current latex release.