# Automatically converting XeLaTeX document to work with pdflatex

Tags: pdftex, xetex, unicode, unicode-math, arxiv

I've got a Literate Agda document, which contains a large number of unicode characters. It builds nicely with XeLaTeX and life is good.

The problem is that arxiv only supports pdflatex, and I'd like to upload the file to arxiv.

Are there any tools/scripts that can process a latex document written for xelatex and add the necessary commands to compile it with pdflatex? Things like `declareUnicodeCharacter` for each used character.

Basically, I'm just looking for a better way than "start compiling with pdflatex, get an error, add the unicode character, repeat".

Most of the unicode symbols are math symbols, so it shouldn't be too hard to map from the characters to TeX commands automatically.

Comment: this defines all the unicode characters known to unicode-math for pdflatex  https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/601583/1090

Comment: note you _can_ submit a xelatex generated pdf to arxiv, just flag it as not-latex and upload the pdf

Comment: If arxiv only supports pdflatex then it supports only 30 years old software.  It would be good to tell the maintainers of arxiv that they overslept.

Comment: @wipet, not only pdflatex, by default it uses latex :-)